# native-navigation stack in tab navigator

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator, tabnavigator

Having a tab navigator, when adding stack-navigator inside it like:

```
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator();
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();
const SearchStack = createStackNavigator();

const HomeStackScreen = () => (
  <HomeStack.Navigator>
    <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
  </HomeStack.Navigator>
)

const SearchStackScreen = () => (
  <SearchStack.Navigator>
    <SearchStack.Screen name='Search' component={SearchScreen} />
  </SearchStack.Navigator>
)
...
<NavigationContainer>
  <Tabs.Navigator>
    <Tabs.Screen name='HomeTab' component={HomeStackScreen} />
    <Tabs.Screen name='SearchTab' component={SearchStackScreen} />
  </Tabs.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

my app looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhGGw.png)

and what bothers me is in the red rectangle in which two names: `HomeTab` and `Home` are displayed that feels redundant. Is there a way to get rid of any of them?

Answer (score 0):

found it. this solves my problem:
`<Tabs.Screen name='HomeTab' component={HomeStackScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).